# Checking if a string is a pangram

Tags: python, strings

This checker works perfectly but I have a strong feeling that I could make this script much more compliant with the "Zen of Python", especially having read a book about it recently. There is no doubt that I made this script much longer than needed, so if you see something I can shorten, please say so.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

myPhrase = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

def is_pangram(phrase):
    c = 0
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    phraseLetters = ""
    for char in phrase:
        for letter in alphabet:
            if char == letter and char not in phraseLetters:
                phraseLetters += char
    for char in phraseLetters:
        for letter in alphabet:
            if char == letter:
                c += 1
    if c == 26:
        return True
    else:
        print phraseLetters, alphabet
        return False

print is_pangram(myPhrase)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be improved and made more Pythonic.  First, there is the `in` and `not in` keyword, which you already know of as you used it.  Why not utilize that instead of doing two loops?

You will have to change the logic slightly:

```
def is_pangram(phrase):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    phraseLetters = ""
    for char in phrase:
       if char in alphabet:
            phraseLetters += char
    for char in alphabet:
        if char not in phrase:
            print phraseLetters, alphabet
            return False
    
    return True
```

I iterate over the letters in `phrase`, checking if they are in the alphabet, and add them to the `phraseLetters` string.  Then, I iterate over the alphabet and check whether each character is in the `phrase`.

This can be simplified even further if you are not interested in printing the letters that are in the phrase.  I would recommend cutting it down even further to this:

```
def is_pangram(phrase):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for char in alphabet:
        if char not in phrase:
            return False
    
    return True
```

This way, you can check whether the phrase is a pangram without always printing to the screen, which is good for re-using the code later; you can then write another method to print the strings in the phrase and the alphabet.  Additionally, I would recommend printing the letters in `phrase` alphabetically so it is easy to see which letter is not in `phrase`, which will also make it easier for any potential debugging you have to do.

## Edit:

Thanks to matsjoyce in the comments, you can simplify it even further to this:

```
def is_pangram(phrase):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    return not (set(alphabet) - set(phrase))
```

This way, you can even return the letters not in `phrase` for ease of reference by just removing the `not` keyword, but you would also have to change the name of the method as `is_something` implies a boolean value being returned.

Additionally, you should probably name `alphabet` in all caps to signify it is a constant variable.

Comment: Thanks for these edits. I was not interested in printing out the results in the first place, that was just the way I was debugging my code when it wasn't working earlier. Again, thank you for for the help.

Comment: You probably can simplify it further by using the `all` function by writing the python equivalent of `alphabet.All(phrase.Contains)`

Comment: @CodesInChaos That would be `all(x in phrase for x in alphabet)`

Comment: Or you could do `not (set(alphabet) - set(phrase))`...

Comment: Or `set(alphabet) != set(phrase)`!?

Answer (score 3):

We want to check that the phrase contains all letters of the alphabet. Such wording more or less suggests your code organization.

Lets rewrite the goal to an equivalent: check that each letter of the alphabet is present in the phrase. Or, even simpler, that no letter of the alphabet is missing. Such wording immediately leads to much simpler approach:

```
for letter in alphabet:
    if not letter in phrase:
        return False

return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd let the set class do all the work.

```
english_alphabet = frozenset('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

def is_pangram(phrase, alphabet=english_alphabet):
    if not isinstance(alphabet, (set, frozenset)): alphabet = set(alphabet)
    return alphabet <= set(x.lower())
```

The use of a set also naturally allows you to print what letters are not in the phrase

```
>>> phrase="The quick red fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> sorted(english_alphabet - set(phrase.lower()))
['b', 'n', 'w']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Never thought of using `set`s. I may need to read up on these, as I known very little about them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whenever you need to perform calculations that involve the alphabet I'd recommend initializing your alphabet variable in the following way:

   ```
   import string
   a_to_z = string.lowercase
   a_to_m = string.lowercase[0:13]
   # etc
   ```
2. Notice that if we remove the second occurrence of the letter `t` from `myPhrase` than your `is_pangram` returns false:

   ```
   is_pangram('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog') # True
   is_pangram('The quick brown fox jumps over he lazy dog') # False
   ```

   To remedy this bug just call `phrase.lower()`.
3. A possible concise (and correct) solution to your problem using the built-in methods for [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) in Python:

   ```
   import string

   def is_pangram(phrase): 
       return set(string.lowercase).issubset(set(phrase.lower()))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal:

```
import string
def meet_pattern(s):
    s = list(s)
    pattern = string.ascii_lowercase + ' '
    return all(pattern[i] in s for i in range(1, len(pattern)))

s = input().strip()
letters = set(s.lower())
if meet_pattern(letters):
    print("pangram")
else:
    print("not pangram")
```

It is certainly not the shortest way to write this code but it is readable.
Also noticed that I am using the `string` module that way I can simply switch to different string types :

```
>>> help(string) # on Python 3
....
DATA
    ascii_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    ascii_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    ascii_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    digits = '0123456789'
    hexdigits = '0123456789abcdefABCDEF'
    octdigits = '01234567'
    printable = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
    punctuation = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
    whitespace = ' \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```